# How can I get this timer script to function within a html/js element in ClickFunnels?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to figure out how to get this to work in a single HTML/JS element in ClickFunnels.

I need to use a div tag instead of body tag but unfortunately I cannot use onLoad with divs as I've recently discovered.

I would highly appreciate any help on this as I've already spent a few hours trying to figure this out.

Here is the HTML

```
<body onLoad="startCount();">
     
    <span class="timerz">Spots remaining: <span id="counterz">19</span></span>
     
</body>
```

Here is the JS

```
<script>
var timer;

function startCount() {
  timer = setInterval(count, 500); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
  var rand_no = Math.ceil(3 * Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
  var el = document.getElementById("counterz");
  var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
  var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
  if (newNumber > 0) {
    el.innerHTML = newNumber;
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = "1"; // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var timer;

function startCount() {
  timer = setInterval(count, 500); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
  var rand_no = Math.ceil(3 * Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
  var el = document.getElementById("counterz");
  var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
  var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
  if (newNumber > 0) {
    el.innerHTML = newNumber;
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = "1"; // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  startCount();
});
```